# Why isn't angular-ui-router updating my nested states? I have to refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have a state on initial signup localhost:3000/#!/ that will show a splash page for new users to sign up. Then after you register and then login, I keep that same url, and have a nested partial view inside that shows all of the user's information. Here is the code:

```
 <section data-ng-controller="IndexController"> 
<h1 mean-token="'home-default'">Hello {{global.user.name}}</h1> 
<div data-ng-if="isLoggedOn() === true"> 
<div ui-view="docTool">
</div> 
</div>
 </section>
```

I read in some of the patches that I could use absolute urls to get to the state I want. In my IndexController, I've tried to say after they login,

```
$state.go('home'); // home is the state for a logged in user
```

and that does not work. I figure in angular-ui-router terms, that explicitly calling the $state would be an absolute url, but maybe I am wrong. I continue to have to refresh in order to get the desired views. Any information that could help me gain a better understanding of this problem is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT** This is my routeConfig:

```
angular.module('mean.system').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // For unmatched routes:
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // states for my app
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                views:{
                    '':{
                        templateUrl: 'system/views/index.html'
                    },
                    'docTool@home':{
                        templateUrl: 'system/views/comps.html',
                        controller:'IndexController'
                    }
                }
            })
        .state('test', {
         url:'/test',
            templateUrl:'system/views/index.html'
        });
    }
]).config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);
```

So, I do not think it is my routeConfig that is the problem. I think it has something to do with my services that serve up the content that is inside the partial view. If I look at my http requests :

```
POST /login 200 271.102 ms - 320
{ _id: 53e11372727c4d911982784f,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  username: 'Tester123',
  name: 'testing',
  __v: 0,
  provider: 'local',
  roles: [ 'authenticated' ] }
GET /admin/menu/main 200 173.611 ms - 556
GET /test 200 228.396 ms - 71
```

This, does not show the view. But here, when I refresh, this is my new http request

```
GET / 200 184.150 ms - -
GET /system/views/header.html 304 170.272 ms - -
GET /system/views/comps.html 304 168.082 ms - - //THIS is different than other... why?
GET /system/views/index.html 304 173.343 ms - - 
{ _id: 53e11372727c4d911982784f,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  username: 'Tester123',
  name: 'testing',
  __v: 0,
  provider: 'local',
  roles: [ 'authenticated' ] }
GET /admin/menu/main 304 167.281 ms - -
GET /test 304 220.457 ms - -
```

Comment: can you also show your routeConfig? Do you have a route defined for 'home'?, something like $state('home', {url: '/home', etc etc)?

Comment: @parsh Updated question with the route config. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Can you try `<div data-ng-show="isLoggedOn() === true">` instead?

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand nothing changed

Comment: So, I hacked together something that worked. Instead of directing my url to $location.url('/'); I changed it to window.location ="/"; This seems to work while the $location does not. It seems like $location was not getting my views correctly.